# TortoiseHg - how refresh list of files from api?

Tags: tortoisehg, mercurial-api

I have in repo some files with specific binary format. I want see its contents.
For such binary file I put in repo specific txt file, containing md5 and nice content from binary.

To minimize manual movements I wrote precommit hook in python that see changes in binary and check is txt-formatted file match new binary one.

If matching fails, hook automatically refresh txt-content and does not allow commit.

Here I need to manually push F5 to refresh list of changes, becouse TortoiseHG does not include in commit files that Modified, but not present in list...

Answer (score 0):

without any others decisions I emulate pressing F5 by ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput :)